# Adjective for object that is pleasant to touch

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for an adjective for the object that is pleasant to touch.

> Do you like the new handle of our door?
>   You bet I do! It's very _______.

Comment: Most of the adjectives that I can think of are concerned with why an object is pleasant to the touch, describing sensation rather than simple pleasantness, such as **warm**, **comfortable**, **soft**.  Actually trying to describe a door handle as giving tactile pleasure seems a bit weird to me, so maybe you should try to be clearer about what you really mean?

Comment: @LeeLeon instead of door handle it could be a computer mouse. Or if we are talking about the materials, then silk. It is pleasant to touch.

Comment: then try **silky**, or maybe **sensuous**

Comment: Sorry, Eduard, but there ain't no such animal. 

Visual beauty might lie in the eye of the sensor but somehow that carries over so that 3,500 years later Helen is still “a beauty” but the sound in the forest fades with or without an ear to hear it.

Smell might be the most evocative memory but taste and yes, touch taper away rather faster.

Comment: sexy? erotic? knob-like?

Answer (score 0):

how about these?

Amazing
Awesome
Blithesome
Excellent
Fabulous
Fantastic
Favorable
Fortuitous
Great
Incredible
Ineffable
Mirthful
Outstanding
Perfect
Propitious
Remarkable
Smart
Spectacular
Splendid
Stellar
Stupendous
Super
Ultimate
Unbelievable
Wondrous

if all else fails, here is a link to 400 words to describe texture
https://owlcation.com/humanities/Describing-Texture-400-words-to-describe-texture